# uninitialized constant AdminController

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I installed activeadmin on existing app with pg database

When I go to:
    http://localhost:3000/admin

I got an error:
`uninitialized constant AdminController`

I did rake     `db:migrate` after activeadmin installation

Tried to reinstall activeadmin but it didn't solve this problem

My routs.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  resources :admin
  resources :posts
  resources :categories
  resources :statuses

  root :to => "home#index"
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan' # or cancancan
gem 'draper'
gem 'pundit'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git
  revision: b1901e8ba6c9a024018a1803c26375b9cb971add
  specs:
    activeadmin (2.0.0.alpha)
      arbre (>= 1.1.1)
      formtastic (~> 3.1)
      formtastic_i18n
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7)
      jquery-rails (>= 4.2.0)
      kaminari (>= 1.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.2, < 5.2)
      ransack (~> 1.3)
      sass (~> 3.4)
      sprockets (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
      sprockets-es6 (>= 0.9.2)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.1.4)
      actionpack (= 5.1.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.1.4)
      actionpack (= 5.1.4)
      actionview (= 5.1.4)
      activejob (= 5.1.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.1.4)
      actionview (= 5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
    activemodel-serializers-xml (1.0.2)
      activemodel (> 5.x)
      activesupport (> 5.x)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (5.1.4)
      activemodel (= 5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      arel (~> 8.0)
    activesupport (5.1.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    arbre (1.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    arel (8.0.0)
    babel-source (5.8.35)
    babel-transpiler (0.7.0)
      babel-source (>= 4.0, < 6)
      execjs (~> 2.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (9.1.0)
    cancan (1.6.10)
    capybara (2.16.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    childprocess (0.8.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    crass (1.0.3)
    devise (4.3.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.2)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    draper (3.0.1)
      actionpack (~> 5.0)
      activemodel (~> 5.0)
      activemodel-serializers-xml (~> 1.0)
      activesupport (~> 5.0)
      request_store (~> 1.0)
    erubi (1.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.18)
    formtastic (3.1.5)
      actionpack (>= 3.2.13)
    formtastic_i18n (0.6.0)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    has_scope (0.7.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.1, < 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.1, < 5.2)
    i18n (0.9.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    inherited_resources (1.7.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.2, < 5.2.x)
      has_scope (~> 0.6)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.2.x)
      responders
    jbuilder (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.3.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    kaminari (1.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-actionview (1.1.1)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.1.1)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-core (1.1.1)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.1.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    method_source (0.9.0)
    mini_mime (1.0.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.10.3)
    multi_json (1.12.2)
    nio4r (2.1.0)
    nokogiri (1.8.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.21.0)
    polyamorous (1.3.1)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    public_suffix (3.0.1)
    puma (3.10.0)
    pundit (1.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    rack (2.0.3)
    rack-test (0.7.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.1.4)
      actioncable (= 5.1.4)
      actionmailer (= 5.1.4)
      actionpack (= 5.1.4)
      actionview (= 5.1.4)
      activejob (= 5.1.4)
      activemodel (= 5.1.4)
      activerecord (= 5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.1.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (5.1.4)
      actionpack (= 5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.2.1)
    ransack (1.8.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      i18n
      polyamorous (~> 1.3)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    request_store (1.3.2)
    responders (2.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (1.2.1)
    sass (3.5.3)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    selenium-webdriver (3.7.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-es6 (0.9.2)
      babel-source (>= 5.8.11)
      babel-transpiler
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.0.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5)
    turbolinks-source (5.0.3)
    tzinfo (1.2.4)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    warden (1.2.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (3.5.1)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.6.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
    xpath (2.1.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activeadmin!
  byebug
  cancan
  capybara (~> 2.13)
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  devise
  draper
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  pg
  puma (~> 3.7)
  pundit
  rails (~> 5.1.4)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.0
```

I understand that the problem is in an absence of AdminController file but as far as I know it should work without it
And I do it on Mac

Comment: What are the commands you've used, what's in your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I updated post with both files

Comment: Have you tried a spring stop and spring start?

Comment: @JayDorsey I've just tried but still no result

Comment: What are the commands you've used to install it?

Comment: @SebastianPalma rails g active_admin:install ,rake db:migrate, rake db:seed

Comment: I don't know where can be the problem really. Try removing the Gemfile.lock, uninstalling the gem, running bundle again, and restarting the server. `rm -rf Gemfile.lock && gem uninstall activeadmin && bundle`

Comment: @SebastianPalma unfortunately, it hasn't helped

Comment: Can you share a repository of your current project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `ActiveAdmin` uses `:admin` as default namespace, if you put `resources :admin` before `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)`, then it will eventually route to `AdminController` resulting in:

```
uninitialized constant AdminController
```

You can overcome the error by either removing the route `resources :admin` or following the other answer by [Piers C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47486697/1977104)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the default namespace for ActiveAdmin (which is :admin). Uncomment the following line in initializers/active_admin.rb

```
  #   config.default_namespace = :hello_world
```